# Unable to pass value from beanshell preprocessor to sampler?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to set value in beanshell inside "CANCEL ORDER" sampler and then use in sampler request body.

Trying

vars.put("orders",Arrays.toString(orderList.toArray()));
and accessing in json request body using ${orders} and its not passing value.

> {
> "orderIds": ${orders},
> "tonce": "${tonce}"
> }

```
   POST data:
   {
   "orderIds": ${orders},
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Your "not passing value" doesn't tell anything to us, if your Beanshell script doesn't work as expected first of all you need to check [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries, if your script fails somehow you will be able to see the error message in the log.
2. It worth checking your `orderList` variable value using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) or printing it to the aforementioned *jmeter.log* file using `log.info()` shorthand
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting as:

   - Groovy has [built-in JSON support](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
   - Groovy [performs much better comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)